# FullCalendar not fetching Events from Feed of DB Query (Laravel)

Tags: json, laravel, fullcalendar-4

My event feed does only work when I hardcode the events in my EventController. Once I get them from database query the events are not displayed though the first event is the exact same I used in the hardcoded event.

Works (Calendar shows event):

```
    public function eventFeed(Request $request)
    {
      $events = array(
      [
            "id" => 1,
            "resourceId" => '1115',
            "title" => 'Wartung Steuerung',
            "start" => '2020-06-11 00:20:23',
            "end" => '2020-06-28 21:21:30',
            ]  
      );
      return json_encode($events);
    }
```

From the calendar view I have a control Ajax call that fetches the same feed as FullCalendar. The received feed is

```
[{"id":1,"resourceId":"1115","title":"Wartung Steuerung","start":"2020-06-11 00:20:23","end":"2020-06-28 21:21:30"}]
```

Does not work (Calendar stays empty):

```
    public function eventFeed(Request $request)
    {
      $start = Carbon::create($request->input('start'));
      $end = Carbon::create($request->input('end'));

      $events = DB::table('toolplanview')->select('id','resourceId','title','start','end')
        ->whereDate('start', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end', '<=', $end)->get();
      return json_encode($events);
    }
```

The feed from the DB query is:

```
[{"id":1,"resourceId":"1115","title":"Wartung Steuerung","start":"2020-06-11 00:20:23","end":"2020-06-28 21:21:30"},{"id":2,"resourceId":"1157","title":"Werkstatt","start":"2020-06-12 09:09:41","end":"2020-06-24 03:45:59"},{"id":3,"resourceId":"1136","title":"Neue Toranlage","start":"2020-06-10 20:29:44","end":"2020-06-23 04:26:38"},{"id":4,"resourceId":"1138","title":"Neue Toranlage","start":"2020-06-10 03:23:12","end":"2020-06-28 11:20:36"}]
```

I dont see why this feed would not work. My calendar:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
            locale: 'de',
          plugins: [ 'interaction', 'resourceTimeline' ],
          defaultView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
          editable: true,
          titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }, 
          header: {
            right: 'today prev,next'
          },
          slotLabelFormat: [
            { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' }, // top level of text
            { weekday: 'short', day: '2-digit' } // lower level of text
          ],
          resources: 'http://localhost/matpro/public/resource-feed',
          events: 'http://localhost/matpro/public/event-feed',
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: The only thing I see wrong is that you're defining `RESOURCE_URL` and `FEED_URL`, but then never using them; you've got `resources: 'http://localhost/matpro/public/resource-feed',` and `events: 'http://localhost/matpro/public/event-feed',` hard coded.

Comment: That was from testing. I removed them from the listing now.

Comment: No worries. Typically, Laravel URLs don't have `/public` in them, but if its working with hard-coded values returned from the URL, then I doubt that's an issue. Are there any errors in your Console? `F12` or `CMD + SHIFT + I` (or `CTRL` on Windows), then Console. Or check your Network tab for the `/event-feed` request, and see what's being returned.

Comment: No errors on console or Laravel log. The network shows the correct request with '/event-feed' and correct 'start' and 'end' parameters. That's why I have the Ajax call that gives me the control Json. I can't see an error in request or return.

Comment: Hmm... It might just be a rendering issue; all of your events are long/overlapping. I'd use the hard-coded approach to try to return and render your events one by one, then slowly add them in combination until either A) They're all displayed or B) something explodes :P

Comment: I just did that and of course they all show up hardcoded. It's just 4 events and I think FullCalendar can handle this, it's almost version 5 now. That's why I can't believe it's a bug, it must be something else.

Comment: That is super bizarre... And yeah, I've worked with full calendar a lot of the years, and while the display of multiple overlapping events ain't pretty, it's never not worked... You've got an interesting one on your hands.

Comment: I would trade "interesting" for "quick solution" ;P Already wasted a whole day on this, it might be good to report this as an issue to the official Github site if nothing comes up here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this behaviour, the issue is the where clause of my DB query:

```
$events = DB::table('events')->select('id','resourceId','title','start','end')->get();
  ->whereDate('start', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end', '<=', $end)->get();
```

When calender e.g. displays a week from 01.06. to 08.06 and one of my (generally longer) events starts on 30.05. and ends on 05.06. this event won't be displayed due to the where clauses in my query. The example dates I picked for testing accidentally overlapped with the calender start or end and therefore did not show up.